# In MVC 3, how can I access the model from a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my application I have two views, that renders the same partial view with model given in parameter, like this:

In View1:

```
 @Html.Partial("_LayoutMyPartialView", new MyModel1())
```

In View2:

```
@Html.Partial("_LayoutMyPartialView", new MyModel2())
```

How can I access the model in the partial view to work with the data?

***UPDATE***

My models does not have the same structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement seems very different.

But still here is a recommended design to achieve what you want (Based on initial question)

1. have a ViewModel that contains instances of Model1 and Model2 , that way you will save having to map 2 differnt objects.

   > ```
   > Public class MyViewModel
   > ```
   >
   > {
   >   public MyModel1 Model1Instance {get;set;}
   >   public MyModel2 Model2Instance {get;set;}
   >   }

Later on just mark in your view `@model` with this single ViewModel. that will give you access to both the Models in your partial while you pass Objects thru controller.

Answer (score 3):

You'll use the `Model` keyword to access your model such that:

```
Model.UserName
```

would give you the UserName property of the object.

Ensure that your partial view is strongly typed too:

```
@model MyModel1
```

Comment: and if in my partial view i have somethig like this   Model.Items.Add(new MyModel());; what can I put in stead of 'new MyModel()'? Thanks

Comment: Why would you be adding new items to a collection within your view?

Comment: it can't be done? I have a dynamic table and it needs initialization on the view

Comment: see my update, if I strongly type the partial view to the first model, the second model data it's not rendered correctly